# How to call model function from view in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

In my view I have an input element that receives a date, once it receives that date it issues an event where I would like to execute a function of the model that makes a query in the database based on the date received. How to do this?

**[update]** **09-03-19** - Call controller from view ajax request, and controller cal model

**[Problem]** - The response of request is my home.php(my view)

The POST has the following url "http://localhost/project/controller/method", and by *inspecting code -> Network*

**General**

```
Request URL: http://localhost/calendar/basecontroller/getagendadate
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: csrf_cookie_name=80c14ce169a5f8110be579a59693e058
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/calendar/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Headers**

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 09 Mar 2019 15:13:34 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/5.6.40
Set-Cookie: csrf_cookie_name=c3d91845df538fa001c64267f440fc32; expires=Sat, 09-Mar-2019 17:13:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
```

**[Controller]**

```
public function getAgendaDate(){
    $sql = 'select * from agenda';
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $send = array('token' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash());

    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: ' . date('r'));
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    }
    exit(json_encode($send, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}
```

**[View]**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //initialize CFG
        CFG = {
            url: '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>',
            token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>',
            name: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>'
        };

        // setup token
        $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: CFG.token}});
        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e,x) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(x.responseText);
            $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: result.token}});
        });
    }).
    // this request run when dispacher an onclick event
    $.ajax({
        url: "basecontroller/getagendadate",
        type: "POST", //send it through get method
        data: { 
            date: '02-02-2019'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
```

[Problem] - The problem is that in response to the request I am receiving the whole code from the index-page. Hence I assume that the problem has to be with .htaccess.

**[.htaccess]** all code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Why when do I request for a controller method? Am I redirected to my home page?

Comment: A possible way would be to make an ajax call to a controller that calls your model and returns feedback after the query is done.

Comment: I do this. But after call controller, the response is my home page.

Comment: @Luckyfella help me, i add my code, and request/response status

Comment: What happens if you use the base_url() when setting the url for the ahax call? I think you need to define the full url path there. url: “<php echo base_url();?>/your-ajax-controller/method“

Comment: happeness that dont enter in function, but request has status 200 and my response is the home.php

Comment: Afaik you need the full http path when doing the ajax call. I guess the url like you have it (controllername/method) resolves to home somehow

Comment: @Luckyfella with complete url i has 403 status request, codeigniter dont permit use url completes

Comment: I stopped using CI before version 3 came out so maybe things changed. In any case I would set up an 'ajax-controller' returning a json response directly just to sort out your routing issues.You could try the .htaccess I used that days:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>